Mass flow rate through a turbine in order to produce a 852 kWh
Over a $30$-day period, $852$ kWh of energy is produced by an electric generator, which has an efficiency of $80$%. The generator is spun by an ideal turbine. What is the mass flow rate, in $\frac{kg}{h}$, that is needed to achieve the $852$ kWh?
In $30$ days there are $720$ hours which means $1.183$ kW is the output of the generator at any given moment. Therefore
$$\dot{W}_t(.8)=1.183kW$$
$$\dot{W}_t=\frac{1.183}{.8}=1.47875kW$$
From the work developed per unit mass of vapor passing through the turbine equation:
$$\frac{\dot{W}_t}{\dot{m}}=h_1-h_2$$
where $h_1$ and $h_2$ are the inlet and outlet enthalpies which I have found to be $2758\frac{kJ}{kg}$ and $1794.8\frac{kJ}{kg}$ respectively.
Rearranging and solving I've found $\dot{m}= 0.00153 \frac{kg}{s}$ and then $\dot{m}= 5.523 \frac{kg}{h}$
Are my calculations correct? This value seems too low to be the right answer.

Yup, maths checks out. 3 to 4 litres per kWh seems a typical industry figure.

1.2 kw is a blow dryer, you need an equivalent amount of energy in.  Your question is missing flow rate of what, at what conditions.
